# C# Not all code paths return a valid in lambda expression of type func

Tags: c#, lambda

First I did try this, my code:

```
timeReports = timeReports.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.TimeReportDatas.First().StartHour)
                  .ToList();
```

But in my project all my projects won't have `TimeReportDatas` so it did crash due it containing no element.

So I changed the code to this:

```
timeReports = timeReports.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ThenByDescending(x =>
{
    TimeReportData firstOrDefault = x.TimeReportDatas.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstOrDefault != null)
        return firstOrDefault.StartHour;
}).ToList();
```

But than I'm left with the following error:

> Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type
>   'Func'

Comment: if (firstOrDefault != null) ... else ?

Comment: What does your lambda return when `firstOrDefault` is `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to return something from all your path.

```
timeReports = timeReports.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ThenByDescending(x =>
{
    var firstOrDefault = x.TimeReportDatas.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstOrDefault != null)
    {
        return firstOrDefault.StartHour;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}).ToList();
```

Or more simpler way:

```
timeReports = timeReports.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                         .ThenByDescending(x => (x.TimeReportDatas.FirstOrDefault() != null) ? x.TimeReportDatas.First().StartHour : 0)
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timeReports = timeReports.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ThenByDescending(x =>
{
    TimeReportData firstOrDefault = x.TimeReportDatas.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstOrDefault != null)
        return firstOrDefault.StartHour;
    return 0;
}).ToList();
```

If firstOrDefault is null then return "0" or new element with standart data. Or use Where(...) for lambda and block "If" - not needed.

Comment: Having it like that would end up 'Cannot convert to null to 'int' because it's a non....